# Swatches Hover Option

Tags: magento2

How to disable the hover option for swatches?

For Ex., Color attribute has the swatches. While we hover a swatch a div displaying that colour in a respective height and width.

Suggest the solution for this please.

Comment: Do you mean disable hover swatch on product listing page, the image change?

Comment: Not the image change.When we hover the swatch (color) for ex., green color swatch, a box with green color will be displayed. I don't want any style when i want to hover the swatches.

Comment: You would like to have a look at the answer here, this might be you solution - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135029/how-can-i-disable-color-swatches-tooltip-in-magento-2

Comment: Found the solution by using the CSS property...

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js 
copy to 
YourVendor/Your_Theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

Change this line:

```
         if (!$element.length) {
                $element = $('<div class="' +
                    $widget.options.tooltipClass +
                    '"><div class="image"></div><div class="title"></div><div class="corner"></div></div>'
                );
                $('body').append($element);
            }
```

in my case i removed only image and keeped title:

```
 if (!$element.length) {
        $element = $('<div class="' +
            $widget.options.tooltipClass +
            '"><div class="title"></div><div class="corner"></div></div>'
        );
        $('body').append($element);
    }
```

but if you want nothing, just remove full :

```
<div class="image"></div><div class="title"></div><div class="corner"></div></div>
```

and keep only this:

```
'>'
```

Answer (score 0):

swatches are rendered from **`vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`** file:

copy that file and save in your theme directory i.e :

**`vendor-direcotry/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`**

search code below  and just comment that out :

```
// Connect Tooltip
        container
            .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
            .SwatchRendererTooltip()
            ;
```

Then flush cache and deploy your static-content ( in default mode ). It will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry still not working

Comment: make sure your customized js file is being loaded / mapped. check in your pub/static folder if it is created