# Disable tooltip show in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tooltip

How can I disable the tooltip in Magento 2? I try to go

> **Admin panel Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog ->Storefront ->Show Swatch Tooltip close it.**

**but still not working.**

Comment: try you using css like --- `body.catalog-category-view .swatch-option-tooltip {
  display:none !important;
  visibility:hidden !important;
}`

Comment: may I knwo in which file?

Comment: your custom css file

Comment: i try it but not working...

Comment: Please check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135029/how-can-i-disable-color-swatches-tooltip-in-magento-2

Comment: yes i try it all before still cannot

Comment: check one more link --- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24270/files

Comment: It’s too complicated. I don’t want to edit too many files. The website will error404

Comment: i also try edit app/code/Magezon/Core/view/frontend/web/css/swatches.css still cannot working